# How do i limit the use of these?

Tags: c#

How can i limit the use of these? They're binded to a button in C# Windows Application Form, It's working. Whenever i click the button 1 time it shows up the textBox2 text + Man, same for the textBox3 text + Women. But when i click it 2 times it shows up as (Let's say textBox2 text is "Hello") Hello Man Man. How can i restrict it to only 1 time for it to never have more than 1 word Man or 1 word Women per line?

```
textBox2.Text += " Man";
textBox3.Text += " Women";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can most directly be accomplished with a simple if statement:

```
if (!textBox2.Text.EndsWith(" Man"))
   textBox2.Text += " Man";

if (!textBox3.Text.EndsWith(" Women"))
   textBox3.Text += " Women";
```

Comment: Thank you and the others that tried helping. I'm new to C# so i needed it simple, just like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Place this inside your button click handler:

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Contains("Man") ? textBox2.Text : textBox2.Text + " Man";
textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.Contains("Women") ? textBox3.Text : textBox3.Text + " Women";
```

it works like this:

```
textbox2.text = condition? first expression:second expression;
```

where if the condition evaluates to true it will return the first expression,else(if returns false) returns the second expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.Tag` property:

```
string originalText = textBox2.Tag + "";
if (originalText.Length == 0)
{
    originalText = textBox2.Text;
    textBox2.Tag = originalText;
}
textBox2.Text = originalText + " Man";
```

And same for the other textbox.

To make it more easy to use and not repeat all those lines for each textbox, use extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddOnce(this TextBox textbox, string text)
    {
        string originalText = textbox.Tag + "";
        if (originalText.Length == 0)
        {
            originalText = textbox.Text;
            textbox.Tag = originalText;
        }
        textbox.Text = originalText + text;
    }
}
```

Then it becomes as simple as:

```
textBox2.AddOnce(" Man");
textBox3.AddOnce(" Women");
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in instance fields:

```
int maleCount = 0;
int femaleCount = 0;
```

Every time someone clicks a button you increment the respective counter and invoke the following helper:

```
void UpdateUI() {
       textBox2.Text = maleCount == 0 ? "" : " Man";
       textBox3.Text = femaleCount == 0 ? "" : " Women";
}
```

Drive the user interface from the data. Don't change the UI it directly. Applying differences to the UI is cumbersome and error prone. It is better to have a common helper function that updates everything at once.